# how to represent a consequence relation in a use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm making a use case diagram for an android application and i want to represent a "consequence" relation but i don't know what to use exactly.To be more clear, i'm calculating something and depending of the result i'm calculating something else, how to repesent that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A use case diagram shows an objective not working, for that use an activity or sequence diagram.

Comment: so no need to represent that?

Comment: Not on the usecase digram.  If you consider it important to document/record it then produce additional digram as necessary.